# L'Hopital rule for sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I had a task to calculate divergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{2n^2+5}x^n
$$
During that task I had to calculate the following limit:
$$
lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ \frac{ln(2n^2+5)}{n}
$$
so naturally I used the L'Hopital rule, but my teacher said that I can't differentiate sequence.

My question: how can I calculate it then? Would making a function $f(x)=\frac{ln(2x^2+5)}{x}$ and calculating it's limit with L'Hopital and then saying that it's limit is the same as the sequence's limit would be a correct solution?

Comment: Why not use the ratio test?

Comment: How did u get that limit during the calculation?

Comment: @mrs I have used Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. If I knew that ratio test was so much easier I would have used it, but I can't change it now. Also I'd want to know how to solve such limit anyway.

Comment: @YvesDaoust he told me that, when I tried to use l'Hopital (which includes differentiating) for the above limit. That's the whole story, I didn't differentiate anywhere else in my solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $lim\ sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=...=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{\sqrt[n]{2n^2+5}}=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{3}{e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(2n^2+5)}}$

Comment: I do not understand this comment section... Why does it matter "how did you get that limit"? Of course you can point that out in the answer, but I believe it's clear he's asking about how to calculate the limit for natural $n$? Correct me if I am wrong, sorry

Comment: @YvesDaoust there are many things in maths that are "obvious" etc., but unfortunately I can't write proofs like that. Also saying that $log(n)$ grows slower than $n$ doesn't solve anthing, since in my situation it is $\frac{log(m)}{n}$ where $m=2n^2+5$ so you can't solve it like that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proof that doesn't use L'Hospital, but it uses sandwich theorem.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{(2n^3+5)}}{n}} $$

First we will substitute $z=2n^3+5$

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{z-5}{2}}}} $$

Now divide by $\sqrt[3]{z}$ in the numerator and denominator.

We get;

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{z-5}{2z}}}} $$

Now we can evaluate the limit of numerator and denominator independently since they both exist.

First the denominator:

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{{\sqrt[3]{\frac{z-5}{2z}}}}=\lim_{z \to \infty}{{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{2z}}}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}$$

And the numerator:

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}}$$

For this we will use sandwich theorem. Note that

$$\ln{z}<z$$ as $z$ approaches infinity so:

$$\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}=\frac{\ln{\sqrt[4]{z}^4}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}=\frac{4\ln{\sqrt[4]{z}}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}<\frac{4\sqrt[4]{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}$$

While we can also say that:

$$\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}>0$$ since it is positive as $z$ approaches infinity.

We showed that:
$$0<\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}<\frac{4\sqrt[4]{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}$$

We can easily evaluate these two limits:
$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{0}=0 \  and  \lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{4\sqrt[4]{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}}=0$$

So, by the sandwich theorem we can conclude that:
$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}}=0$$

Our overall limit is now:

$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\frac{\ln{z}}{\sqrt[3]{z}}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{z-5}{2z}}}}=\frac{0}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}}=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly apply L'Hopital's Rule to compute the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2n^2+5)}n$; you will get that it is equal to $0$.

Having said this, I have no idea *why* you would want to do that to study that power series. All you have to do is to compute\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left\lvert\frac{3^{n+1}}{2(n+1)^2+5}x^{n+1}\right\rvert}{\left\lvert\frac{3^n}{2n^2+5}x^2\right\rvert}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2+5}{2(n+1)^2+5}3\lvert x\rvert\\&=3\lvert x\rvert.\end{align}So, your series diverges when $\lvert x\rvert<\frac13$ and diverges when $\lvert x\rvert>\frac13$. Actually, it follows from the comparison test that it converges when $\lvert x\rvert\leqslant\frac13$.

Comment: I used Cauchy-Hadamard theorem ($\lambda=lim\ sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$). My teacher explicitly told me that I can't use l'Hopital here, since I can't differentiate series (in $\frac{ln(2n^2+5)}{n}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: I've already sent my soultion to my teacher and he told me to just correct this one part, so I can't change to using ratio test now. Please just tell me how to calculate this limit for natural n.